# show a div when certain word is typed not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, textarea

Hey all so I'll keep it short. I know there've been some questions asked similar to this but none of them are able to answer what I'm trying to achieve. This is what I want the code to do:

- Show a div when forward slash "/" is typed in textarea
- Not show a div when forward slash is not typed
- hide the pop up when the forward slash is deleted/backspaced

I can achieve the first two with the following code I'm working with right now: https://jsfiddle.net/jtk37vs8/1/. However the problem is, whenever I type forward slash and then delete it, the pop up still stays there. I'm new to JS and the code is kinda unorganized but it's quite easy to understand. So basically I'd appreciate if any of you could at least tell me if there is any straightforward way to achieve this? Thank you for your patience and reading my query.

```
function getCaretCoordinates() {
  let x = 0,
    y = 0;
  const isSupported = typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined";
  if (isSupported) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    // Check if there is a selection (i.e. cursor in place)
    if (selection.rangeCount !== 0) {
      // Clone the range
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      // Collapse the range to the start, so there are not multiple chars selected
      range.collapse(true);
      // getCientRects returns all the positioning information we need
      const rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
      if (rect) {
        x = rect.left; // since the caret is only 1px wide, left == right
        y = rect.top; // top edge of the caret
      }
    }
  }
  return { x, y };
}

function getCaretIndex(element) {
  let position = 0;
  const isSupported = typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined";
  if (isSupported) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    // Check if there is a selection (i.e. cursor in place)
    if (selection.rangeCount !== 0) {
      // Store the original range
      const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      // Clone the range
      const preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      // Select all textual contents from the contenteditable element
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      // And set the range end to the original clicked position
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      // Return the text length from contenteditable start to the range end
      position = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  }
  return position;
}


$("#contenteditable").bind("keypress", function toggleTooltip(e) {
  const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  
if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == '/') {
    
    
    const { x, y } = getCaretCoordinates(); 
  
  $(".tooltip").show();
    // tooltip.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
    tooltip.setAttribute( "style", `display: inline-block; left: ${x - -10}px; top: ${y - 160}px`
    );
  } 
  
  else  if (document.getElementById('contenteditable').innerHTML.indexOf("/") != -1) {
   // $(".tooltip").hide(); 
   // tooltip.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
    tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
     
 }  
   
  // else if (document.getElementById('contenteditable').innerHTML.indexOf("/") >=0) {
    // tooltip.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
    //tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");    
 // }
    
 else { 
  //  $(".tooltip").hide();
   // tooltip.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
    //tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
   
    
  } 
} )
```

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated for a long time. Use `.on()`.

Comment: @Barmar, just tried .on(), nothing changed

Comment: Why would anything change? They do the same thing.

Comment: You only want to show the DIV when forward slash is the last character they typed? Or whenever there's a forward slash anywhere in the input?

Comment: In the keypress handler, check if the key is backspace and the character to the left of the caret is `/`.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes essentially that. Whenever forward slash is the latest character typed. Not when there's a forward slash anywhere in the text. And when you delete/backspace the slash, the div should also disappear. Does that make sense?

Comment: When you type backspace, and the character to the left of the caret is `/`, it means the `/` is about to be deleted.

Comment: What should happen if they type `//` and then delete the second `/`? Should the DIV stay or go?

Comment: @Barmar Either works. Preferably it should go.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. BTW, doing it this way is definitely not the most performant way to be handling this, but it works.

First, you need to change your event listener to keydown. Keypress doesn't work for backspace / delete, if I remember correctly. Once you do that, it's as easy as adding what you already have.

```
if (e.keyCode == 46) {
    // ... check if '/' is in the text area value, you already have this code
    // OR 
    // ... check if the last index of document.getElementById('textarea-id').value is a '/'
}
```

There's a lot wrong with the conditionals here though, but using indexOf (like you have already) will be the most user friendly, I guess. That way, nothing changes in the case of multiple '/', and the tooltip is deleted when all the '/' are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value **==** instead of **!=** as you want to hide if the slash is missing

```
 else  if (document.getElementById('contenteditable').innerHTML.indexOf("/") == -1) {
```

when the typed character is not a slash hide it

```
  tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
```

as the backspace is not handled by the keypress event, we will a use a different handler to handle it in a keyup event as follow

```
    $("#contenteditable").on("keyup", function toggleTooltip(e) {
   if (document.getElementById('contenteditable').innerHTML.indexOf("/") == -1) {
     // $(".tooltip").hide(); 
     // tooltip.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
      tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");

   }   
});
```

Working fiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/BETOMBO_Mariot/a5ntzjg4/

Comment: okay so here's the thing. This works, but this doesn't satisfy the second point then. It shouldn't show the div when the forward slash is not typed. In your code if you type forward slash and then type something else, the div doesn't go away as it should. Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does "not typed" mean? Because it is typed, just not the last character.

Comment: i have separete the  handler of the event keypress and keyup as when you put them together the character is not detected. And i have hide the div when the  typed character is not a slash
you can check again the fiddle code  here https://jsfiddle.net/BETOMBO_Mariot/a5ntzjg4/

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problems you commented under the other answers. This just looks for the last character.

```
$("#contenteditable").on("keyup", function(e) {
  const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  let content = document.getElementById('contenteditable').innerHTML;
  

  if(content[content.length - 1] == "/") {
    const {x, y} = getCaretCoordinates(); 

    tooltip.setAttribute("style", `display: inline-block; left: ${x + 10}px; top: ${y - 160}px`
    );
  }
  else {
     tooltip.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
  }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sra7ufLy/76/

Comment: Okay so this does seem to do the job so thanks for the input! However there's this minor issue that whenever I put a forward slash and then move the cursor somewhere else, the div doesn't go away. It seems tweaking this just a little should do the job but I've been messing around and haven't gotten too far. :(

Comment: Also, another thing that's acting super weird is that this only works on the first line of the paragraph. If you press enter multiple times and then type forward slash it doesn't show the div.

Comment: You can see what’s going on by `alert()` or `console.log()` the content. When you hit Enter it returns `hit forward slash to access pop up box<div><br></div>` and any following input is placed inside that `div`. Hence it won’t recognize it as the last character because `>` will be the last one.

Comment: You can fix that by using `textContent` or `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.